# OVSIntPort with Netplan

Tags: networking, netplan, tag

I'm looking the way to deal with OVSIntPort and netplan. I just want to configure the address, MTU and leave the other OVS things with ovs-vsctl which will be saved on OVSDB. Since Network Manager replace previously created OVSIntPort on OVSDB, so I must redefine it including its tag too (by using OVS_OPTIONS on ifcfg- script) if it was previously existing. This behavior is not happen with systemd-networkd.  Should I move to systemd-networkd just for this OVSIntPort?

Best regards,

Comment: you can find the work around in the link below, Hope it help
https://askubuntu.com/questions/1333570/is-there-a-way-to-create-an-open-vswitch-internal-port-with-netplan/1373467#1373467

Answer (score 5):

I'm not sure if I understand the question correctly, but if you're using Netplan v0.100 (currently in Ubuntu Groovy & Focal -proposed) you could be using Netplan's native Open vSwitch support to create OVS ports/interfaces.

For example (OVS Bridge: ovs0):

```
network:
    version: 2
    renderer: networkd
    openvswitch:
        ports: # to create OVS internal patch ports
            - [patch0-1, patch1-0]
    ethernets:
        eth0: {} # physical ethernet interface
    bridges:
        ovs0:
            addresses: [192.168.0.10/24]
            interfaces: [patch0-1, eth0]
            mtu: 9000
            openvswitch: {} # this is an OVS port
```

Netplan, using the systemd-networkd renderer, can create OVS patch-ports, bridges, bonds and (vlan) fake bridges for you, using `ovs-vsctl` in the background. You can then modify OVSDB according to your needs via individual `ovs-vsctl` commands.

For further reference, please have a look at the netplan/OVS documentation and the OVS example below:
https://netplan.io/reference/#common-properties-for-physical-device-types
https://github.com/CanonicalLtd/netplan/blob/master/examples/openvswitch.yaml

Comment: What I want is just give IP address to br-provider OVS internal port and leave all bridges, ports and interfaces configuration to ovs-vsctl to be saved on OVSDB.

Comment: So you could either create the 'br-provider' OVS internal port automatically via netplan and have it assigned an IP address, as shown in the example above (e.g. 'ovs0'). netplan will save this information in OVSDB for you and you can modify it afterwards.

Or you would need to manually create the systemd-networkd .network file in `/etc/systemd/network/br-provider.network` and handle everything manually (https://www.freedesktop.org/software/systemd/man/systemd.network.html)

Answer (score 3):

I stumbled upon the same sutiation lately. And thanks to Lukas Maerdian's answer I made it to understand what he ment by it.
So in the end my config for netplan was like this:

```
network:
  ethernets:
    real_ethernet_port0: {some regular parameters}
    real_ethernet_port1: {some regular parameters}
  bridges:
    your_ovs_int_port:
      openvswitch: {}
      dhcp4: false
      addresses: [192.168.1.1/24]
      gateway4: 192.168.1.1
      and so on...
```

You see, the catch is to nest it under **bridges:** category (not ethernets!) and it has to have this **openvswitch: {}** line. Which btw can have other different parameters, pls follow Lukas's links.
What author meant is we have already configured virtual switch via ovs-vsctl with ovs internal ports created automatically. The only thing is to configure address via netplan because system clears it after reboot if you configured it through **ifconfig** or **ip address add** commands in shell.