# Is there a way to create an Open vSwitch internal port with netplan?

Tags: networking, virtualization, netplan, network-bridge

As per the Title really. I can't work out if there's a way to do this or not. The only mention of ports in the [docs](https://netplan.io/reference/) are "patch ports" as pairs of ports. The [example](https://github.com/canonical/netplan/blob/master/examples/openvswitch.yaml) shows the use of these patch ports, but it's still not clear at all if you can 'define' these ports in a way that can receive configuration on them.

Basically trying to create the equivalent configuration from [Proxmox Open vSwitch, Example 3](https://pve.proxmox.com/wiki/Open_vSwitch#Example_3:_Bond_.2B_Bridge_.2B_Internal_Ports_.2B_Untagged_traffic_.2B_No_LACP):

```
# Loopback interface
auto lo
iface lo inet loopback

# Bond eth0 and eth1 together
allow-vmbr0 bond0
iface bond0 inet manual
    ovs_bridge vmbr0
    ovs_type OVSBond
    ovs_bonds eth0 eth1
    ovs_options bond_mode=balance-slb vlan_mode=native-untagged

# Bridge for our bond and vlan virtual interfaces (our VMs will
# also attach to this bridge)
allow-ovs vmbr0
iface vmbr0 inet manual
    ovs_type OVSBridge
    ovs_ports bond0 vlan1

# Virtual interface to take advantage of originally untagged traffic
allow-vmbr0 vlan1
iface vlan1 inet static
    ovs_type OVSIntPort
    ovs_bridge vmbr0
    ovs_options vlan_mode=access
    address 192.168.3.5
    netmask 255.255.255.0
    gateway 192.168.3.254
```

I can achieve the `vmbr0` and `bond0` interfaces with the following netplan config, but don't know how to create the internal port (named `vlan1`).

```yaml
---
network:
  version: 2
 
  ethernets:
    eth0: {}
    eth1: {}
 
  bonds:
    bond0:
      interfaces:
        - eth0
        - eth1
      openvswitch: {}
 
  bridges:
    vmbr0:
      interfaces:
        - bond0
      openvswitch: {}
```

*I am aware I can add layer 3 configuration directly to `vmbr0`, but I believe I need an internal port as I want this interface to handle VLANs in the same way other ports for containers/VMs will. Answers explaining how this assumption is wrong also appreciated!*

*I am also constrained to using Open vSwitch as libvirt [doesn't support "standard linux bridges"](https://libvirt.org/formatdomain.html#setting-vlan-tag-on-supported-network-types-only).*

Answer (score 1):

Netplan does not currently support to explicitly define arbitrary OVS internal ports (as of v0.102).

What you can do, though, is defining a VLAN on a given OVS bridge like this:

```
  vlans:
    #implicitly handled by OVS because of its link
    vlan1:
      id: 100
      link: vmbr0
```

This will create a "type=internal" Port/Interface for you on the OVS bridge defined by the "link" setting, as can be seen in this test scenario: https://github.com/canonical/netplan/blob/master/tests/integration/ovs.py#L184
That port can then receive arbitrary configuration (via netplan or ovs-vsctl).

Answer (score 0):

I came accross the same issue, base on @Lukas Maerdian suggestion and bug report [here](https://bugs.launchpad.net/netplan/+bug/1927301), here is the work around i manage to get it working

```
---
network:
  version: 2
  renderer: networkd
  ethernets:
    eth0: {}
    eth1: {}
  bonds:
    bond0:
      interfaces:
        - eth0
        - eth1
      parameters:
        mode: balance-slb
      # by default the vlan is already untagged, no extra option needed here.
      openvswitch: {}
  bridges:
    vmbr0:
      interfaces:
        - bond0
      openvswitch: {}
  vlans:
    #implicitly handled by OVS because of its link
    # For Untag VLAN
    vlan1:
      id: 0
      link: vmbr0
      addresses: [192.168.3.5/24]
      gateway4: 192.168.3.254
      openvswitch: {}
    # For VLAN 10
    vm10:
      id: 10
      link: vmbr0
      openvswitch: {}
```

Also notice the the ordering of the vlans, it need to be at the last step according to that bug report.